# How to effectively deal with temporary helpers that require ownership?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17

One aspect of memory management in C++ is bothering me at the moment. The main concept in C++ for memory management is ownership. Every object is owned by one or (via shared pointers) multiple things. Those things can be other objects or scopes/blocks. Ownership can be transferred (via unique pointers). Once thing (object, scope/block) ceases to exist, it drops ownership for everything that it owns and all objects without a further owner cease to exist as well.

Regarding APIs, one has to express if one takes ownership for an object or not:

- Taking exclusive ownership is expressed by taking something by value or by rvalue reference.
- Taking shared ownership is expressed by using a shared pointer.
- Not taking ownership is expressed by using an lvalue reference.

This works out pretty well in most situations, but I have trouble with one kind of situation: I've got a function that does not need to take ownership, but it uses *temporary* helper objects that merely reference some other objects, i.e. they have members that are either pointers or references. If I want to avoid dangling references, this basically means that the helper objects need to claim shared ownership over the objects they are referencing. Now, I have two options:

1. modify the function to take a shared ownership pointer, but then, it is leaking implementation details. Basically, all arguments to all functions would be of that kind ... like they are in most garbage-collected or reference-counted languages.
2. use references / raw pointers in my helper classes to express shared ownership and rely on the user to make sure that the helper class instances are destroyed before the shared resources are.

I have no clear guidelines on when to make which decision at the moment, mostly I tend to use the latter approach. But now, I introduced a bug that was not easy to find it and cost me some time.

I am trying to find out how to avoid those situations in the future. During debugging I wrote some code that was able to detect that kind of situation (by using reference counting that can be deactivated in production mode) (but used it on the wrong objects ;-)).

This seems like a reasonable approach, but before going down that road I wanted to find a few things out:

1. Is this really a reasonable approach or is there something wrong with the way I design the APIs for my software?
2. Is there anything in the standard library that I am not aware of that makes this task easy?
3. Or any 3rd party libraries?

Adding a code sample for clarification:

```
struct AutoAddEndLineAdaptor
{
    template <class T>
    AutoAddEndLineAdaptor &
    operator<<( T && t )
    {
        _out << std::forward<T>( t ) << std::endl;
        return * this;
    }

    std::ostream & _out;
};

void printStuff( std::ostream & out ) {
    AutoAddEndLineAdaptor{ out } << "Hello" << "World";
}

auto breakStuff( std::string file ) {
    std::ofstream o( file );
    return AutoAddEndLineAdaptor( o );
}
```

The `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor` class requires shared ownership to become safe, i.e. make misuse like in `breakStuff` hard, but `printStuff` does not.

Comment: Can you add a code sample?

Comment: [tag:Rust] has life time in its type system to fully handle those cases.

Comment: "*If I want to avoid dangling references, this basically means that the helper objects need to claim shared ownership over the objects they are referencing.*" If that's true, if they truly are temporary objects, then they don't need to claim ownership over those objects. They're just referencing them.

Comment: @NicolBolas The problem is that whether those objects are temporary or not depends on the context they are used in, but whether they claim ownership or not doesn't. This limits reusability, but that is something I can live with. However, it hard for me to deal with the fact that it becomes so easy to accidently introduce undefined behaviour through dangling references into the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adding a code sample for clarification:

Your example shows the foundation of your problem.

In `printStuff`, the type `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor` is exactly what you describe: a temporary helper object. It is an implementation detail. It does not persist past the end of the function.

In `breakStuff`, this is not the case. `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor` is no longer a mere implementation detail of the function; it is a *part of the interface* of yours system. Oh sure, you've (ab)used `auto` to hide the name. But you cannot hide the fact that `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor` is now part of your system's interface. And therefore, the relationship between `breakStuff`, `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor`, and the user's provided object is part of that interface too.

You are dealing with temporary helpers correctly. The problem is that you're not recognizing a case where the temporary helper isn't actually a temporary helper.

`breakStuff` indirectly returns a reference to an object the user owns. That is a fundamental part of its interface. Therefore, you need to decide how best to inform the user of this. `breakStuff` could have a comment over it, informing the user that the object it returns contains a reference to the parameter, so the user has to avoid deleting it until they're finished with the return type.

Not that every `operator<</>>` overload for streams effectively does this. So it's not an uncommon tactic. Your problem is that users aren't acutely aware of it because you returned it indirectly, hidden behind `auto`.

Or you can have `breakStuff` claim ownership over the parameter, so that it can be transferred to the return value. If that is logically what `breakStuff` is about, then it makes sense.

Personally, I'd go with option 1, for your specific case. But this is a case-by-case kind of thing.

BTW, this is also why you should *avoid* `auto` return deduction unless its actually necessary (ie: the return type is a complex type and its use is obvious to the user). If you had put `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor` in the return type, it would be more obvious what you're doing.

Comment: I am sorry for using `auto`. It seems like I did not put a lot of thought into this aspect of the example. If you don't mind, I'll change this in the example above. Regarding my problem, I think that I want the compiler to fail in most situations that are similar `breakStuff` and I am looking for the most elegant solution to this problem that adds next to no overhead for production builds.

Answer (score 2):

> I've got a function that does not need to take ownership, but it uses temporary helper objects that require shared ownership.

If the function has to use such helpers that require (shared) ownership, then transitively the function requires (shared) ownership. Solution: Use shared pointers, and forget about the assumption that the function doesn't need it.

If the use of the helpers is not needed to implement the function, and the function must not take ownership, then using those helpers is not an acceptable way to implement the function. Solution: Don't use the helpers. Instead use something that does not require ownership.

If the function must not take ownership, but must be implemented using helpers that take ownership, then you are at a stalemate. Either adjust the requirements, or abandon the design.

---

Note that it is possible to assume the ownership of a referenced object within a function. It does not constitute as taking ownership as long as the temporary ownership is released and does not persist beyond the function.

So, you might technically be able to assume the ownership temporarily, as long as you can prove that the implementation detail does not leak in any situation. This can be problematic when exceptions are involved.

---

> The `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor` class requires shared ownership, but `printStuff` does not.

Neither own the referenced object. They both reference the object. It is safe to use `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor` within `printStuff`.

It is not OK to return a `AutoAddEndLineAdaptor` that refers to a local variable, such as in `breakStuff`.

Comment: It is hard for me to accept that ownership is transitive. This rules out capture-by-reference in lambdas, the adaptor pattern for non-copyable types, as far as I can see, a whole lot of range-based programming and more. It takes a lot of composability out of the language.

Comment: @MarkusMayr why would it rule out capture-by-reference in lambdas? Referencing is not taking ownership. Neither do you implicitly take ownership in a range based loop. If by *"helper objects that require shared ownership"* you actually intended to say that the helpers need to reference the objects, then you don't have a problem.

Comment: I'd argue that the point of shared ownership is to avoid merely referencing objects because the latter approach can easily lead to dangling references. Could you clarify what the difference between taking shared ownership and referencing objects is? I think this is part of the answer to the question I seemingly was unable to ask.

Comment: @MarkusMayr to take shared ownership ~~ `make_shared` or copying an existing `shared_ptr`. To reference an object (owned by something else) ~~ `auto& ref = object` or `auto* ptr = &object`.

Comment: Ok, I think I edited the question to be more precise regarding those terms. What I meant is that the helper class merely references objects (what I called sharing ownership). I am looking for effective ways to catch dangling references. One way would be to use shared pointers (what you called sharing ownership).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sort of ephemeral ownership system by wrapping a raw pointer into `shared_ptr` instances that have a deleter that is a no-op:

```
void function_that_does_not_own(T *ptr)
{
    shared_ptr<T> non_deleting_share(ptr, [](T*){} );
    function_that_requires_shared(non_deleting_share);
}
```

When all of the shared pointers are gone the deleter gets invoked... but since it does nothing, it doesn't really effect the 'true' ownership of the ptr.

Of course, you really, *really* make sure that it's doing what you expect. This sort of thing is very error prone in two ways:

- You have to make sure that `function_that_does_not_own` truly doesn't invoke anything that would cause the true owners of `ptr` to release the object. (of course, you have to do this anyways for any function that uses a pointer without sharing in its ownership)
- You have to make sure that `function_that_does_not_own` truly doesn't invoke anything that would have side effects that ultimately expect `ptr`'s lifetime to extend beyond this function call.

It's very easy to miss edge conditions that would violate either or both bullet points — it can sometimes be *very hard* to actually guarantee that `function_that_does_not_own` does not need to participate in pointer ownership.

If there is any question at all (and there probably is if your function has to use other objects that intend to share ownership of the pointer), then you should presume your function really does need to share ownership of the pointer, and take a `shared_ptr` argument.